# How to pronounce Stirling Numbers of Second Kind ${n\brace k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, notation, soft-question, stirling-numbers

The Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind, ${n\brace k}$, count the number of ways to partition an $n$-element set into $k$ unlabeled non-empty parts and are rather useful for several introductory questions in combinatorics alongside the other earlier taught binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$ and factorials, and so on.

The binomial coefficients have a standardized way of reading them aloud in English, being "$n$ choose $k$."  Is there anything similar for Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind?  Or for the Stirling Numbers of the First Kind?

In my head, when typing them out or thinking of them, I often read them with the TeX commands as "n brace k"... but if I were to try to use a more suggestive phrase that helps imply the meaning of the notation I might prefer "$n$ partition $k$" or "Second Stirling $n$ $k$."

I am curious how other people read this aloud in a classroom setting or in their own head.

Comment: I was in fact thinking of asking you one of these days :)

Comment: For the Stirling numbers of the first kind, "$n$ cycle $k$" sounds very natural. I can't think of anything for ${n \brace k}$ which sounds anywhere near as good.

Comment: $n$ curly bracet $k$ is my favorite

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The book [Concrete Mathematics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025) by Graham, Knuth & Patashnik suggests “$n$ subset $k$” for ${n\brace k}$ and “$n$ cycle $k$” for ${n \brack k}$ (pp. 258–259 in the second edition).